# Merging potentially empty dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Is there a way I can merge several dataframes together given that some may be empty? For example:

```
    A:
                PeriodEndDate      value
        0 2021-02-28 23:59:59        200
        1 2021-05-31 23:59:59        250
        2 2021-08-31 23:59:59        175
        3 2021-11-30 23:59:59        100
        4 2022-02-28 23:59:59        150

    B:
                PeriodEndDate      value
        0 2021-02-28 23:59:59         99
        1 2021-05-31 23:59:59         50
        2 2021-08-31 23:59:59         40
        3 2021-11-30 23:59:59         50
        4 2022-02-28 23:59:59         40

    C: Empty DataFrame

Desired output:
                PeriodEndDate          A         B         C
        0 2021-02-28 23:59:59        200        99         0
        1 2021-05-31 23:59:59        250        50         0
        2 2021-08-31 23:59:59        175        40         0
        3 2021-11-30 23:59:59        100        50         0
        4 2022-02-28 23:59:59        150        40         0
```

Note: I would be running this on a bunch of dataframes, so A and B could also potentially be empty. When I try using the concat method, the PeriodEndDates are not merged together and cause duplicates instead.

Comment: You probably want to use DataFrame.join() https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html with how='outer'. You may also need to change the index to PeriodEndDate... The outer join will introduce nulls - which can be addressed with the `fillna()` method.

Comment: You may just filter from list of dfs by `len(df) > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is

- df.merge()-if you want to merge to a specific dataframe,
- pd.concat()- If they have similar y axis
- pd.join() - If you want to join only specific columns

All off these methods have the capability of circulating the lack of connection beetween the dataframes, there is outer join method. Which basically says IF there is no key wether on the left side(df doing the merge) or the right sided (df receiveing the merge). Fill it with null values. After that is just a matter of handling nulls. Would recommend utilizing comprehension, to do it quickly.